# Find the maximum volume of a box inscribed in a tetrahedron bounded by coordinate axes and a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

The full question:
Find the maximum volume of a box inscribed in the tetrahedron bounded by the coordinate planes and the plane $x+\frac{1}{2} y + \frac{1}{3} z = 1$.

I tried graphing the plane on geogebra, and I can see the tetrahedron formed by the plane and the axes. However, I'd prefer to find these points analytically rather than graphically, and when I tried doing this I ran into a dead end (I tried just plugging in x=0, etc.). This could be a function of it being late and my brain not working when I'm tired, though.

However, once I get the points of the vertices of the boundaries, I'm not sure what to do from there. I know it'll eventually become an optimization problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a classical issue of maximization under constraint:

$$\text{maximizing} \ f(x,y,z):=xyz \ \text{under the constraint} \  g(x,y,z)=x+\frac12y+\frac13z-1=0. \tag{1}$$

Let us express this optimization issue under the form of a proportionnality of partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$:

$$\begin{cases}\lambda &=&yz\\\lambda \frac12 &=&xz\\\lambda \frac13 &=&xy\\\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

with a certain Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ that we eliminate by taking the ratio of the second equation to the first and then the ratio of the third equation to the second:

$$y/x=2 \ \text{and} \ z/y=3/2 \tag{3}$$

$$y=2x \ \text{and} \ z=3y/2\tag{4}$$

into the expression of $g$ gives :

$$x+\frac12 2 x+\frac13 \frac32 2 x-1=0$$

giving :

$$x=\frac13$$

Using (4), one obtains:

$$y=\frac23 \ \text{and} \ z=1.$$

The dimensions of the box are therefore, along the $x,y,z$ directions resp.

$$\frac13 \times \frac23 \times 1$$

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response! I did not realize that this was such a simple application of the lagrange multiplier method, so I will try to develop that intuition.